# How do I detect a long press on the app icon?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to detect if the user has long-pressed the app icon on the home screen?

I can detect if a quick action is selected, but I'd also like to detect if the Home Screen Quick Action menu is displayed.

[image: Home Screen Quick Action Menu]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Note that your app may not even be running when the menu is presented.

Comment: We'd like to track how many users are using the Quick Action menu.  Obviously, not all long-presses of the icon will convert to a selection on the menu.  Good point that the app might not even be running.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to detect if the user has long-pressed the app icon on the home screen?

No. Cocoa is *event* driven. Without an event, your code doesn't run. You don’t get any event unless the user taps one your quick actions or Today extension.

Comment: The long-press of the icon is an event.  Apple uses it to display the Quick Action menu.  I just don't know if that's exposed.